# How do you open Python 3.8 IDLE?

Tags: python, python-idle

sorry for the total noob question.

I just downloaded Python 3.8 from the official Python website and I am just wondering, how do you open the IDLE as I would like to start writing some code?

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: save any file with the `.py` extension, then right click edit with IDLE?

Comment: If you are a beginner I would recommend using Jupyer Notebook (or something similar tool) that you can install executing the `pip3 install jupyter` command.

Comment: thanks guys I will give it a try

Comment: On Windows, open the start menu, go down to a Python directly, and click the IDLE entry.  I keep IDLE pinned to my taskbar after that.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you just used the Windows installer, but just pressing the Windows key and searching for IDLE did the trick for me.

[image: Window search]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffqbT.png)